# Easyphp Devserver phpinfo reports wrong php version

Tags: easyphp

I have downloaded the latest easyphp devserver version 16.1.1 and then downloaded/installed the php 7.0.6 x86 update. Apache is also 32-bit.

When I start apache using php 7.0.6 and then load phpinfo(), it still reports that the php version is 7.0.4.

The dashboard says that apache is running with php version 7.0.6 though.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this turned out to be simple. I rebooted the computer. The next time I ran the EasyPHP shortcut, it picked up the 7.0.6 php version automatically.. I guess whatever it finds as latest when this first runs on startup ends up taking precedence over what you select when restarting the apache server through the dashboard. Sounds like a bug.