# Can't change PHP version in EasyPHP Devserver

Tags: php, apache, easyphp, easyphp-devserver

I'm using EasyPHP Devserver 17, and I can't seem to upgrade from PHP 5.6.26 to 7.4.

I've got it running in EasyPHP, when I start the server it says:

> Apache 2.4.39 x64 - PHP 7.4.6 x64 Port: 8080

I've changed the references in httpd-php.conf to look like this:

```
#LoadModule php5_module "C:/www/eds-binaries/php/php5630vc11x86x191223082005/php5apache2_4.dll"
LoadModule php7_module "C:/www/eds-binaries/php/php746vc15x64x200518170402/php7apache2_4.dll"
#PHPIniDir "C:/www/eds-binaries/php/php5630vc11x86x191223082005/php.ini"
PHPIniDir "C:/www/eds-binaries/php/php746vc15x64x200518170402/php.ini"
SetEnv TMP "C:/www/eds-binaries/tmp"
```

Yet three strange things happen when I run phpinfo():

1. it says PHP version 5.6.26 (even though the original installation looks like it was 5.6.30 in httpd-php.conf based on the folder name)
2. It lists my php.ini path as "C:\WINDOWS" which does not contain a php.ini
3. It has my "Loaded Configuration File" as "C:\www\eds-dashboard\eds-dashboard.ini"

I've tried restarting the server, I've tried restarting my computer, I've even tried a Virtual Host with the following code [based on this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269083/set-path-to-php-ini):

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80> #Note: I've also tried port 1111 and 8080.
PHPINIDir "C:\www\eds-binaries\php\php746vc15x64x200518170402\php.ini"
</VirtualHost>
```

...to try and force it to read the right .ini file, and still nothing.

I don't even know if that's necessary, honestly, it just seemed like it might work.

The most fascinating thing is, PHP 5.6 is installed *nowhere* on my computer. It's not in my PHP folder, it's not in my environment variables, it does not exist. Obviously the CLI doesn't reflect the whole situation, but along with the server dashboard, 7.4 comes up there and in PHPStorm just fine so I know it's at least on offer.

Plus, when I start my server with the 7.4 folder open, Windows tells me for a second that the file "can't be previewed because it's in use," so something is touching it.

The only other thing I could think of is that the php.ini file in my PHP folder has an extension_dir value of `"C:\www\eds-binaries\php\php746vc15x64x200518170402\ext"` while the ini file that gets loaded from the C:\www\eds-dashboard folder has a value of `"./extensions"`, but changing that yielded no results.

And finally, the strangest thing is that when I run `phpinfo();` from inside my project, it comes back with 7.4.6, even when the dashboard doesn't.

I officially have no idea what's going on here. Can somebody **please** tell me what (probably minor) thing I'm missing?

Thank you!

---

Note: Please don't merge this with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750417/easyphp-devserver-phpinfo-reports-wrong-php-version), it's a different version of the server and the answer didn't work for me.